# Replace blank spaces in an array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, replace

I have to replace blank spaces (" ") of all the values from an array in shell script. So, I need to make an array like this:

```
$ array[0]="one"
$ array[1]="two three"
$ array[2]="four five"
```

looks like this:

```
$ array[0]="one"
$ array[1]="two!three"
$ array[2]="four!five"
```

Replacing every blank space to another character **with a loop or something, not changing value by value.**

Comment: You mean `array[0]=one`, maybe? `array[0] = one` isn't an assignment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
array=('one' 'two three' 'four five') # initial assignment
array=( "${array[@]// /_}" )          # perform expansion on all array members at once
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"           # print result
```

Answer (score 4):

Bash shell supports a find and replace via substitution for string manipulation operation. The syntax is as follows:

```
${varName//Pattern/Replacement}
```

Replace all matches of Pattern with Replacement.

```
x="    This    is      a      test   "
## replace all spaces with * ####
echo "${x// /*}"
```

You should now be able tp simply loop through the array and replace the spaces woth whatever you want.

Answer (score 3):

```
$!/bin/sh

array=('one' 'two three' 'four five')

for i in "${!array[@]}"
do 
    array[$i]=${array[$i]/ /_}
done

echo ${array[@]}
```

Comment: Much better now, though the use of `echo` is unfortunate, especially with unquoted arguments. `printf '%q\n' "${array[@]}"` would be a more effective demonstration of where the boundaries between array elements are, since `echo` doesn't visually distinguish between an argument with a space and two separate arguments (and leaving out your quotes means that something that would otherwise have been one argument with a space gets transformed into multiple arguments during string-splitting phase).

Comment: One last issue here -- the /bin/sh shebang doesn't guarantee a shell with arrays will be used to run this script.